# Android:is it possible to share the bitmap image without saving it

Tags: android, bitmapimage

I am creating bitmap image in my application and i dont want to save it on phone. If user want he can share it with other apps.I tried many things but m not able to share the image with other app without saving it. Is there really any way by which we can share the image with other android application without saving it? or we must have to save it first and then share. Kindly suggest.

Comment: what things have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The Bitmap saved is not on disk, but only in RAM. Other apps are not allowed to read your's app's allocated RAM. The ways for your app to export volatile data are:

1. Write byte data to a large `Parcel`, and put it in an `Intent` extra.
2. provide data over to a network socket or via a custom content/file provider etc.

But even for these methods to work, you need other apps to know how to fetch data. Which is very unlikely unless the other app is also programmed by you.